# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied & sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

First time playing around with sqlite3 and I am running into this error when trying to send scraped data to my table.

```
    c.executemany('''INSERT INTO stats VALUES(?,?,?,?)''',(Player, Disposals, Goals, Fantasy,))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 23 supplied.
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats (Player TEXT, Disposals INT, Goals INT, Fantasy INT)''')

df = pd.read_html('https://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=10544')
Player = df[11].iloc[1:25, 0]
Disposals = df[11].iloc[1:25, 3]
Goals = df[11].iloc[1:25, 5]
Fantasy = df[11].iloc[1:25, 16]

c.executemany('''INSERT INTO stats VALUES(?,?,?,?)''',(Player, Disposals, Goals, Fantasy,))
```

I initially used c.exceute but ran into the following error

```
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO stats VALUES(?,?,?,?)''',(Player, Disposals, Goals, Fantasy))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I wouldn't be surprised if it was a simple formatting issue that im over looking, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are using a dataframe, why not just use df.to_sql?  Dataframe columns can' t be dumped directly to sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

`Player`, `Disposals` and etc. are Series object. This means you are passing a Series object to `executemany` method. However, `executemany` expects a list of tuple like following

```py
lang_list = [
    ("Fortran", 1957),
    ("Python", 1991),
    ("Go", 2009),
]
```

To solve this, you can zip them together with `list(zip(Player, Disposals, Goals, Fantasy))`